# How to simulate salinity gradient in experiment?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, oceanography

I feel like the question is probably fairly fundamental. I have to recreate oceanic turbulence in terms of salinity and temperature gradients. Temperature is easy - heater. What should I do with the salinity? Salt and water form a solution pretty fast. How do I create salinity gradient similar to oceanic conditions?

Comment: A gradient of salinity is quite easy to create in stationary water, but I think it is not what you ar looking for. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I have a sloshing machine to generate turbulence and I need to add the gradient of salinity. I was thinking of not dissolving the salt completely and let it rest on the bottom while sloshing. That way for some time there would be a gradient near the bottom of the tank.

Comment: I got some experience when I set up a gradient of salinity in a fish tank to have a demonstrative apparatus to show bending of a laser beam as effect of a gradient in the refraction index. If salt is put in the tank before filling it with water and water is poured gently, a quite stable gradient can be established lasting even a few days.